# In corporate office, how to ask superior about why he can not proceed with a proposal?

Tags: politeness, formal

Basically, I want to ask a very senior person why a work cannot be proceed in other way instead of current way.

From my side I have following ways to ask. But are there any better ways?

- この方法で対応できない理由は、ちなみに何でしょうか？
- この方法で進めない理由がわかりますでしょうか？

Comment: We don't do unfocused translation checks.

Comment: As long as your senior colleague is reasonable enough, both make sense and are fine (Just as I believe is the case with  other languages, native speakers are generous about foreigners' mistakes.)

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend the second. You would sound like you are testing your superior’s ability to understand the situation.